# Python Crawling Siblings

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, web-crawler

I am crawling some websites and now I need to find some values. Even though it's seems simple to do. For some reason I can't get it done.

This is the piece of code where I can find the values:

```
<dl class="product-specs--list">
    <dt class="product-specs--item-title">
        Fabrikantcode               </dt>
    <dd class="product-specs--item-spec">
        BX80646I74790K              </dd>
    <dt class="product-specs--item-title">
        Artikelnummer               </dt>
    <dd class="product-specs--item-spec product-specs--item-spec-even">
        476816              </dd>
    <dt class="product-specs--item-title">
        Merk                </dt>
    <dd class="product-specs--item-spec">
        Intel               </dd>
    <dt class="product-specs--item-title">
        Garantie                </dt>
    <dd class="product-specs--item-spec product-specs--item-spec-even">
        3 jaar              </dd>
    <dt class="product-specs--item-title">
        Garantietype                </dt>
    <dd class="product-specs--item-spec">
        Carry-in-garantie               </dd>
</dl>
```

And this is mine peace of code:

```
link = 'http://www.processorstore.nl/product/476816/category-212276/intel-core-i7-4790k.html'
source = requests.get(link)
plain = source.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain)

for dt in soup.findAll('dt', {'class': 'product-specs--item-title'}):

    spec = dt.text.strip()

    if spec == 'Serie':

        print(spec) # It does print Serie

        # Now i need to find the Next_sibling: Core i7
        # This is NOT working :(
        dd = spec.find_next_sibling("dd", {'class': 'product-specs--item-spec'})
        print(dd)


    elif spec == 'Threads':
        print(spec)
    else:
        print("######### something else")
```

I did try several things, but without success.

Comment: Since you call ``spec = dt.text.strip()``, your variable ``spec`` should contain a string instead of a beautiful soup element. You could verify that by printing ``print type(spec)``.

Answer (score 3):

You should find the next sibling from the `dt` instead of a `spec` (which is a unicode string):

```
dd = dt.find_next_sibling("dd", {'class': 'product-specs--item-spec'})
```